# How to add definition as item

Tags: itemize, tex-general

I want to add definition as a list item. I have the script shown below. But it add the definition after a new line of the item's dot. This does not look right for me. I want the definition to be added just after the item's dot.

```
\documentclass[conference,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{example}{Example} %for using \beging{example}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition} %for using \beging{definition}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{definition} [My Definition] \end{definition}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put it in a `minipage`, for example, `\item \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}\begin{definition} [My Definition] \end{definition}\end{minipage}\medskip`

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around? What's the purpose of stating a numbered definition inside an itemized list?

Comment: Also check out the `description'` list.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes True, but that requires one to specify a width, which I doubt OP wants to do.

Comment: @JPi True, which I gave as an example.  I am confident that some combination of `linewidth` and `\leftmargin`, etc. can calculate the desired width exactly.

Comment: What should the output look like?